# What was the first assassination/murder recorded on film?

Tags: assassination

Was it the murder of Archduke Franz-Ferdinand?

Comment: Do you mean motion picture or still photography?

Comment: @Luke: I meant motion, but still is also interesting.

Comment: Zapruder film???

Comment: Does the murder of [Topsy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topsy_(elephant)) (1903) count?

Comment: @YannisRizos: I really don't know... Hat off for digging it up, anyway.

Comment: Note for those researching this - a lot of early "combat" and "crime" footage were re-enactments supplied by the Edison Company for newsreels. (Edison went so far as to have a model of San Francisco built, set on fire and shook by a camera assistant, and sold this as footage of the San Francisco Earthquake).

Comment: Re murder of Archduke Franz-Ferdinand: it seems as if the relevant reel has gone missing: his [arrival](http://www.firstworldwar.com/video/ferdinand.htm) at the Sarajewo town hall and his [funeral](http://www.firstworldwar.com/video/ferdinandfuneral.htm) in Vienna in 1914 are both on film ...

Comment: As for the first photographed (unsuccessful) assassination, my vote goes to the assassination attempt on William Jay Gaynor, the mayor of New York, on August 5, 1910: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Jay_Gaynor#Assassination_attempt

Comment: Thank you for your question; could you give us an overview of the [research you have done so far](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599) and explain what you find to be unclear or missing? Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) may be helpful.

Comment: As a near miss, [McKinley was photographed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassination_of_William_McKinley) shortly before he was shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential resource is [Wikipedia's list of filmed assassinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aFilmed_assassinations).  Can anyone find any of those that preceed [Alexander I of Yugoslavia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_I_of_Yugoslavia) in 1934? I picked that one at random, but a bit of google suggests that this may be the first assassination captured on film.

Comment: Should this have been a comment, all those years ago?

Answer (score -2):

My guess without going to Wikipedia is Alexander I of Yugoslavia while he was in Marsaille visiting a French leader. I think it was around 1934. I wonder if Austrian Chancellor Dolfuss's assassination (from around the same time) was caught live on radio or film.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).